# Trying to set public network interface speed to 0

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to set the public network interface speed to 0. I am getting the following error,

```
{
  "error":"Speed cannot be null and must be 0 (Disconnect), 10, 100, 1000, or 10000.",
  "code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

The URL is: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/100862242/setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed

The method is GET.  The parameter passed is:

```
{
   "parameters" :
    [
        "newSpeed" : 0
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the payload like this:

```
{  
 "parameters":[  
    0
]}
```

Comment: I changed the content to be {
 "parameters":[
    0
]}     and I still get the error.   sorry new lines don;t persist here

Comment: You have to change the method to POST.

Comment: @Gary Sutherland: please "upvote" and "accept" this response